# Python code to extract txt from PDF document

Tags: python, pdf, txt

I have been trying to convert some PDFs into .txt, but most sample codes I found online have the same issue: They only convert one page at a time. I am kinda new to python, and I am not finding how to write a substitute for the .GetPage() method to convert the entire document at once. All help is welcomed.

```
import PyPDF2
 
pdfFileObject = open(r"F:\pdf.pdf", 'rb')
 
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObject)
 
print(" No. Of Pages :", pdfReader.numPages)
 
pageObject = pdfReader.getPage(0)
 
print(pageObject.extractText())
 
pdfFileObject.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with a `for` loop. Extract the text from the pages in the loop and append them to a list.

```
import PyPDF2

pages_text=[]
with open(r"F:\pdf.pdf", 'rb') as pdfFileObject:
    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObject)

    print(" No. Of Pages :", pdfReader.numPages)
    for page in range(pdfReader.numPages):
        pageObject = pdfReader.getPage(page)
        pages_text.append(pageObject.extractText())

print(pages_text)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, mate! This worked.  I will add here that if someone wants to store it as a .txt file they just need to add:

lines = pages_text
with open('pdf.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in lines:
        f.write(line)
        f.write('\n')